# Pandas - How to control column order when appending to a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am having a devilishly difficult time figuring out how to take a DataFrame with N rows, and a Series with N rows, and another Series with N rows, and joining it all together. Here's what I'm doing (wrong):

```
print df['Survived'].shape               # Series should be 1st column
print pd.Series(kmeans.labels_).shape    # Series should be 2nd column
print pd.DataFrame(X_pca).shape          # DataFrame should be remaining columns
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
new_df['Survived'] = df['Survived']
new_df['ClusterId'] = pd.Series(kmeans.labels_)
new_df = new_df.append(pd.DataFrame(X_pca))
print new_df.shape
print new_df.columns.values
```

and the output is:

```
(1309,)
(1309,)
(1309, 9)
(2618, 11)
[0L 1L 2L 3L 4L 5L 6L 7L 8L 'ClusterId' 'Survived']
```

Two things I don't understand:

1. The sequence of the columns is all wrong. I've tried starting with the DataFrame, then appending the 'ClusterId' Series, then finally the 'Survived' Series, but the column order of the resulting DataFrame is exactly the same.
2. After appending the dataframe with DataFrame.append, the number of rows of the resulting dataframe has doubled

I've tried reading the documentation but I'm having a really tough time finding anything covering exactly what I'm trying to do (which oddly doesn't seem like an unusual thing to do). I've also attempted `pd.concat([Series, Series, DataFrame], axis=1)` but that throws an error: `pandas.core.index.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`

Comment: It would help if you gave some idea of what the actual Series and DataFrames look like.  From the error in your attempt to `pd.concat` I suspect that the index for one or more of your Series/DataFrame doesn't match the others.  The index matters!  Also, `append` will naturally append *rows* not columns, fyi.

Comment: Let's pretend I have no concept of indexes and I'm just thinking of this as raw data. I'm starting with a dataset in a DataFrame. I transform a lot of columns into fewer columns, and calculate a cluster id using the new columns. So I have one column I want to keep from the original dataframe, and I want the new cluster id column I created, and the new reduced column set I transformed. They're all lined up in the correct order (I guess this is where the index factors in? I really don't care, they're all in the correct order already I just want to combine them.

Comment: It appeared as though using `ignore_index=True` would be a solution here (for using concat()) but the error remains.

Comment: Please, get good advice from other comments and answer and give a simple example showing and reproducing your problem.

Comment: @joaquin I assume you downvoted my question because you don't think I did a good enough job asking it? That's pretty lame. I  think I made a decent effort at describing what I'm trying to do, I figured people who aren't total beginners at pandas would know exactly what I was talking about. I'm also more than willing to provide more information. I'm sorry I don't know ahead of time exactly what you want me to provide to make it easiest for you to answer, but that's no reason to downvote me.

Comment: You may want to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and more specifically the part that says: 'Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem' and the links there. This will help pandas beginners to learn from your question and the possible answers and help a pandas expert not to expend more time than needed trying to understand what your problem is. If you look at the @Ajean answer or at the pandas docs it is not so difficult to create a simple dataframe to clearly depict the problem, what you have and the result you want to obtain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debugging pandas without test data is extremely hard, but here is a working example of something which I *think* approximates your steps.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=np.random.randn(5), b=np.random.randn(5),
                       c=np.random.randn(5)))
s1 = df['b']*2
s1.name = 's1'
s2 = df['b']/4
s2.name = 's2'

new_df = pd.concat([s1, s2, df[['a','c']]], axis=1)
```

This produces

```
         s1        s2         a         c
0 -2.483036 -0.310379  1.152942 -1.835202
1 -1.631460 -0.203932  1.299443  0.524964
2  1.264577  0.158072 -0.324786 -0.006474
3 -0.547588 -0.068449 -0.754534 -0.002423
4  0.649246  0.081156  0.003643 -0.375290
```

If anything else is going wrong, try to see where what you have differs from the minimum example here.

**EDIT**:
An illustration of why the index is important:

```
In [64]: s1
Out[64]: 
0   -2.483036
1   -1.631460
2    1.264577
3   -0.547588
4    0.649246
Name: s1, dtype: float64

In [65]: s2
Out[65]: 
1   -0.310379
2   -0.203932
3    0.158072
4   -0.068449
5    0.263546
dtype: float64

In [66]: print(pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1))
          0         1
0 -2.483036       NaN
1 -1.631460 -0.310379
2  1.264577 -0.203932
3 -0.547588  0.158072
4  0.649246 -0.068449
5       NaN  0.263546
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll work from here and see if I can work out the issue. I don't really understand what indexing has to do with it, I have no meaningful index and the `ignore_index` parameter doesn't make any difference - maybe because I'm using axis=1??? If I can't sort it out from here I'll provide some actual data

Comment: The index matters because pandas is database-savvy ... `concat` will only put things together that have the same index (i.e. if one of your Series has row indices of [0,1,2] and one of them has indices of [2,3,4], it will give you a DataFrame with indices [0,1,2,3,4], with NaNs in the places where there is no overlap)

Comment: @ElDuderino Added an illustration to the post

Comment: Thanks a lot, that definitely helped me figure it out! My initial dataframe was constructed from multiple files->dataframes concatenated together and I hadn't reindexed that, so that is definitely causing the issue. I should be able to sort it out pretty quickly from here